Not able to get a value in the alert inside a component
I am working on a webapp in sveltekit and I am not able to get the value in alert (for debugging).
I have a component ModalFlight.svelte. I am not able to get the value of token retrieved in page.sever.ts in it.
The value retrieved is a token from a third party api which i want to be available to other components as well.
I don't want to use cookies here because I want to increase my understanding as to where I am going wrong \n
I am able to get that value in page.server.ts
Code below is for ModalFlight.svelte where I am not seeing the value in alert.
<script lang="ts">
    import my_store from '$lib/Store';
    import { get } from 'svelte/store';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';

    $: tokenString = '';
    my_store.subscribe((data) => {
        tokenString = get(my_store).token;
        console.log('subscribed value' + tokenString);
    });

    function fetchFlights() {
        alert(get(my_store).token);
    }
    
</script>

<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events a11y-no-noninteractive-element-interactions -->

    <!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-static-element-interactions -->

    <div on:click|stopPropagation class="flightbar">
        
                <button class="btn" on:click={() => fetchFlights()}>Find Flights</button>
    </div>

 

Code for page.server.ts :
import { amedeus_client_id } from '$env/static/private';
import { amedeus_secret } from '$env/static/private';
import $my_store from '$lib/Store'
import { get } from 'svelte/store';
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
urlencoded.append("client_id", amedeus_client_id);
urlencoded.append("client_secret", amedeus_secret);

function getToken():any{
    let data;
    const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: urlencoded,
        redirect: "follow"
      };
      
      fetch("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => {
            const tokenDetails = JSON.parse(result); 
            data = tokenDetails;
            $my_store.set( {'token': tokenDetails.access_token});
            $my_store.update((data) => {
                return {'token': tokenDetails.access_token}
            });
            console.log('hello'+JSON.stringify(get($my_store)));
          //  console.log(JSON.stringify(token));
          //  token.set(tokenDetails.access_token);  
          //  console.log("printing result : "+token)
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        return data;
}

export async function load() {
    return {
      posts:  getToken()
    }
  }

import {
  writable
} from 'svelte/store';

const my_store = writable({
  'token': 'default value'
});



my_store.set({
  'token': ''
});

export default my_store;



Too much code and too badly formatted. Try creating a minimal reproduction first.

So I removed the stores solution altogether as the problem probably looked of the loading sequence. I passed the value in page data and got it working.
